# Customization of user editable checkboxes implemented via QAbstractItemModel in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I have QTreeView with QAbstractItemModel. Some particular columns are supposed to have user defined checkboxes. I have done so by overriding QAbstractItemModel::data() function and by sending check state for Qt::CheckStateRole role as shown in the code.

I am getting checkboxes and am able to check and uncheck them successfully.
But the requirement is to customize some of these checkboxes. Basically I need to differentiate some checkboxes from the others by any method for eg: fill the checkbox with blue, make the boundary of the checkbox blue or any other method. But I am not sure how to change checkbox styling as I am creating checkbox via model.

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();
    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole && index.column() == COLUMN_WITH_CHECKBOX)
    {
        //return Qt::Checked or Qt::Unchecked here
    }
    //...
}

bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return false;
    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if ((Qt::CheckState)value.toInt() == Qt::Checked)
        {
            //user has checked item
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //user has unchecked item
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need is implement your own `ItemDelegate`

```
class CheckedDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CheckedDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~CheckedDelegate();

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex& index) const;

};
```

In this delegate you must implement custom editor and custom item painting. To create custom editor:

```
QWidget *CheckedDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QCheckBox *chBox = new QCheckBox(parent);
    //customize editor checkbox
    QString strQss = "QCheckBox::indicator:checked { image: url(:/icons/pic/checkboxChecked.png); } ";
    strQss.append("QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked { image: url(:/icons/pic/checkboxUnchecked.png); }");
    chBox->setStyleSheet(strQss);
    return chBox;
}

void CheckedDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QCheckBox *chBox = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*> (editor);
    if (index.data(Qt::CheckStateRole).toInt() == Qt::Checked)
    {
        chBox->setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        chBox->setChecked(false);
    }
}

void CheckedDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QCheckBox *chBox = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*> (editor);
    model->setData(index, chBox->isChecked() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
}

void CheckedDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(GetCheckboxRect(option));
}
```

To calculate checkbox geometry use

```
QRect GetCheckboxRect(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option)
{
    QStyleOptionButton opt_button;
    opt_button.QStyleOption::operator=(option);
    QRect sz = QApplication::style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ViewItemCheckIndicator, &opt_button);
    QRect r = option.rect;
    // center 'sz' within 'r'
    double dx = (r.width() - sz.width()) / 2;
    double dy = (r.height()- sz.height()) / 2;
    r.setTopLeft(r.topLeft() + QPoint(qRound(dx),qRound(dy)));
    r.setWidth(sz.width());
    r.setHeight(sz.height());

    return r;
}
```

Then implement custom painting. In this example I use pixmaps to customize checkbox so I also paint only pixmaps.

```
void CheckedDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
    if (index.data(Qt::CheckStateRole).toInt() == Qt::Checked) {
        QApplication::style()->drawItemPixmap(painter, GetCheckboxRect(option), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, QPixmap(":/icons/pic/checkboxChecked.png"));
    } else {
        QApplication::style()->drawItemPixmap(painter, GetCheckboxRect(option), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, QPixmap(":/icons/pic/checkboxUnchecked.png"));
    }
}
```

And set your delegate (in my example I have `TableTiew` not `TreeView`)

```
CheckedDelegate *chDel = new CheckedDelegate(this);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, chDel);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something on these lines and I am able to customize the checkboxes now.